# Can I install a game onto an Xbox 360 from an image on a flash drive?

Tags: xbox-360

I scratched my NBA 2k13 game disc and didn't install it into my Xbox 360. I asked my friend to download his NBA 2k13 copy to my usb flash drive. Is there a way I can install 2k13 to my Xbox 360 from the flash drive?

Comment: This questions appears off topic on the grounds of game piracy.

Comment: [Scratches can be fixed!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16234/how-do-i-repair-a-scratched-game-disc)

Answer (score 2):

No.  If it was possible, it would be extremely easy to pirate games using hacked ROMs.  What you are attempting to do is also illegal, because you are attempting to duplicate your friend's disc.  Your friend didn't "buy the game" and its binaries, but rather he bought the right to use those binaries on that specific game disc.  Think of it like using a fake ID.

The only way to legally get a new copy of the game is by buying a new one.

Comment: Not true, In the US it is perfectly legal to borrow a game from a friend and install the game to the hard drive. However, ripping the game from the disc, and then continuing to have the .iso on a flashdrive is the illegal part. Using something that microsoft offers to install the game to a hard drive is still within the legal limits of the Terms of Use and EULA.

Comment: I meant to edit the first line to read "hard drive from a disc."

Answer (score 2):

You can do this and it is legal as long as you can put your scratched disk in and it tells you what the game is. You can have your friend install it onto your hard drive or just move it onto a flash drive. This is a copy of the disk, not disk specific which is legal to do and the reason being is you can't just go to the game and play it.

It will tell you to insert your disk which you will want to do, but the first time you play the game instead of hitting "play game" as you usually would, you will need to hit options and then hit play game. Done correctly you won't hear your game spin because it's playing from the installed copy your disk; it just confirms you own a legit copy to play the installed disk file from hard drive. If you hear it spinning just dashboard then do it again. Once you do it correctly you can just hit play game as you usually would.

Note: if your disk is unreadable or just says play game and doesn't work then buy a new one is your only option, but if it reads what the game is you're in luck.

Answer (score 2):

Have your friend come over and install his copy of NBA2k13 onto your hard drive. As long as your game can still be read by the 360 you're in the clear, Also this particular method is 100% legal and is allowed by microsoft.

Source: First Hand Experience and Community Ambassadors.

EDIT: Also confirmed with Xbox Support via [twitter](https://twitter.com/Cheat117cole108/status/365520186448691200).

Comment: Mhh... I would be more comfortable with a link as source, that backs up your first hand experience.

Comment: Okay, I asked Xbox Support, however, copying the disc to a flashdrive is still a no-no. Look at twitter link.

Comment: @5pike There is lots of precedent for things like this going back decades. The content owner only cares that you are using a valid, bought disc in the drive when the game is launched. They don't actually care if the on-disk copy was installed from the same disc or not, just so long as you've got a legal disc during the disc-check part of game launch.

Comment: And, the virtue of this answer is that it only works if the OP really *does* legitimately have a friend with a second copy of the game disc. If they were saying "my friend" in the OP to mean "I found a download from the Internet", then this answer will not help them pirate the game at all!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Which is where I was focusing, not the burned ".iso" that his friend PB Torrent gave him. Trust me in the aspect that I've tried that position and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, that was more a comment to other users reading it, than to you specifically. There's a strong anti-piracy policy here (for various good reasons), so that was my attempt to wave a big "hey look, this is really not supporting piracy" flag to others who might not notice the difference. :) The twitter link is a great addition though.

Answer (score -1):

No, but you can connect your hard drive to your PC and copy the game.