# Super Smash Bros. Brawl for Wii freezes at map selection menu

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, super-smash-bros-brawl

Recently I decided to play Super Smash Bros. Brawl for my Wii. The game appeared to load fine, until I tried to play a multiplayer game. I selected some characters, and as soon as I pressed <kbd>+</kbd>, the selection menu worked for about 2 seconds and then froze completely, giving a monotone drone (presumably the music stopping).

I tried cleaning the disk and console, deleting the game data to remove any custom maps, made sure there was no dust or lint in the drive, and it still didn't work. I tried custom Brawl and normal Brawl, but both gave the same result.

When this happens, my Wii won't respond to buttons, but I can reboot it. It appears to work fine, all the other games load, but SSBB won't go past that menu, no matter what I try. The cause is most likely a scratch on the disc.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have an SD card in the Wii? Is anything hack-related on it? If you have a hack that disguises itself as a custom stage, and Brawl tries to load it before a match, you get a freeze.

Comment: @Toomai I've checked, and I do have an SD card, but no hacks at all for the game. And it's crashing on the regular map (included with the game) selection. I'll add that to the description.

Comment: Might still be worth trying without the SD card in there, if you have any custom stages that could potentially be corrupted. (The game loads custom stages even on the normal stage menu, so it might be a factor.)

Comment: @Toomai I deleted my game data (through the data management menu in settings), it still freezes.

Comment: Take a look at the disc itself to make sure there isn't a scratch. If there's a scratch on the section where the map selection screen is stored, it could cause this problem.

Comment: @Brian Is there a way to fix the scratches?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI As long as it isn't a severe scratch, it should be possible. See http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Scratched-Video-Game

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI [I'm fairly certain that a search would do wonders.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16234/how-do-i-repair-a-scratched-game-disc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I actually did have a couple of hacks on my SD card. Removing the SD card fixed the game.

It does not matter what the hacks are, I removed them from my other games one by one and it still caused problems.