# Far Cry 4 won't install completely on my xbox 360

Tags: far-cry-4

I recently bought Far Cry 4. During the game data installation it gets about 1/3 of the way through and quits saying the installation cannot be completed. I've tried several things, but nothing seems to work. I even tried in on another Xbox but had the same results. The disc looks fine. I don't know what the problem is but there is one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thank You... Sincerely Coy Osbon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I repair a scratched game disc?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16234/how-do-i-repair-a-scratched-game-disc) Seems like the only logical cause. Try to return the disc if you bought it from a store.

Comment: The disk Is in good shape not any scratches perfect mirror finish,,m, Plus I have a professional Disc repair machine that could fix any scratches  or surface problems ... I bought off of Ebay so duplicate is possible   Thank You for your answer and response

Comment: And you're sure it's a legitimate copy? Otherwise, I think the problem must lie with your console, although it is weird that both Xboxes weren't able to read all of the data.